# Jython/Java communicate with usb midi device using javax.sound.midi.*. (lividinstruments)

Tags: java, jython, midi, javax.sound.midi, jython-2.7

I'm trying to communicate with an usb midi controller using the midi classes from javax.sound package. I successfully got input from device, but i can't work out how to communicate with device. 
The device is livid [OhmRGB](http://wiki.lividinstruments.com/wiki/OhmRGB).
According to wiki i should send some SysEx messages to get response with parameters. I didn't work with java libraries before, so maybe i use it in the wrong way. You'll see the method below to request some data from device, but device doesn't respond on any system messages.

Pseudo-code(jython):

```
class Communicator:
  def __init__(self):
     self.outputs = []
     self.inputs = []
     self.input = None
     self.output = None

  def getMidiDevices(self):
     devices = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()
     for dev in devices:
       midi = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(dev)
       # get outputs
       if midi.getMaxReceivers() != 0: #(-1 or positive)
         self.outputs.append(dev)
       if midi.getMaxTransmitters() != 0:
         self.inputs.append(dev)


  def openOutput(self, dev):  #!right device resolved somewhere
    self.output = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice( dev )
    self.output.open()

  def openInput(self, dev):
    self.input = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice( dev )

    inReceiver = SomeReciever()
    self.input.getTransmitter().setReceiver(inReceiver)

    self.input.open() #input open and receiver print messages from dev.

  def requestDevice(self):
    device = self.resolveOutput()
    self.openOutput(device)

    data = [240, 0, 1, 97, 0, 7, 8, 247]
    _bytes = bytearray(b"")
    for i in data: _bytes.append(i)
    # create message from array  
    message = SysexMessage(str(_bytes), len(_bytes)) # it works correctly
    self.output.getReceiver().send(message,-1L)

    self.output.close()



   communacate = Communicator()
   communacate.openInput()

   time.sleep(2)
   communicate.requestDevice()
```

When I open the input, the receiver class handle incoming midi messages.
When i request device i do not see any response from device (i expect it on input receiver). I requested all available output ports and even sent messages on input receiver for any case. I also reproduced it in java and got the same result. I think i use the wrong way to get response from device.

Huge thanks,
Anton

Comment: Does "I successfully got input from device" refer to this Java code?

Comment: Nope, in java i only tried to send sysex messages on the midi outputs. [The link](http://pastebin.com/WmQKT8fs)